# Insert multiple characters in string at once

Tags: ruby

Where as str[] will replace a character, str.insert will insert a character at a position. But it requires two lines of code:

```
str = "COSO17123456"
str.insert 4, "-"
str.insert 7, "-"
=> "COSO-17-123456"
```

I was thinking how to do this in one line of code. I came up with the following solution:

```
str =  "COSO17123456"
str.each_char.with_index.reduce("") { |acc,(c,i)| acc += c + ( (i == 3 || i == 5) ? "-" : "" ) }
  => "COSO-17-123456
```

Is there a built-in Ruby helper for this task? If not, should I stick with the insert option rather than combining several iterators?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to match some pattern. A regex-based solution would probably work, e.g. `str.sub(/(.{4})(.{2})(.{6})/, '\1-\2-\3')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `each` to iterate over an array of indices:

```
str = "COSO17123456"
[4, 7].each { |i| str.insert i, '-' }
str #=> "COSO-17-123456"
```

Comment: `[4,7].each_with_object('-',&str.method(:insert))` seems fun :)

Comment: ...or should this be: `[4, 7].sort_by { |n| -n }.each { |i| str.insert i, '-' };
str #=> "COSO-171-23456"`? Only the OP knows.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no I think it was pretty clear `"COSO-17-123456"` is the intended result especially given the second example using `3` and `5` as indices.

Comment: @engineersmnky, perhaps I should be asking the OP if it would not be more convenient to adopt my interpretation, so that when determining where to insert characters one would not have to consider the index offsets resulting from some or all of the previous insertions.

Answer (score 1):

You can uses slices and `.join`:

```
> [str[0..3], str[4..5],str[6..-1]].join("-")
=> "COSO-17-123456"
```

Note that the index after the first one (between 3 and 4) will be different since you are not inserting earlier insertion first. ie, more natural (to me anyway...)

You will insert at the absolute index of the original string -- not the moving relative index as insertions are made.

If you want to insert at specific absolute index values, you can also use `..each_with_index` and control the behavior character by character:

```
str2 = ""
tgts=[3,5]
str.split("").each_with_index { |c,idx| str2+=c; str2+='-' if tgts.include? idx }
```

Both of the above create a new string.

Answer (score 0):

`String#insert` returns the string itself.

This means you can chain the method calls, which can be a prettier and more efficient if you only have to do it a couple of times like in your example:

```
str = "COSO17123456".insert(4, "-").insert(7, "-")
puts str
COSO-17-123456
```

Your `reduce` version can be therefore more concisely written as:

```
[4,7].reduce(str) { |str, idx| str.insert(idx, '-') }
```

I'll bring one more variation to the table, `String#unpack`:

```
new_str = str.unpack("A4A2A*").join('-')
# or with String#%
new_str = "%s-%s-%s" % str.unpack("A4A2A*")
```